# XML DomIt converting &amp; to &

Tags: php, xml, parsing, dom, xhtml

Using [DomIt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/domit-xmlparser/) to parse a valid XHTML document.

For some reason, Domit is reverting valid & in links to plain & which breaks the validation.

I would be expecting the other way around if any fix were to be made.

This is the original tag:

```
<link href="index.php?format=feed&amp;type=atom" rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 1.0" />
```

This is the same tag after parsed:

```
<link href="index.php?format=feed&type=atom" rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 1.0" />
```

This is the relevant code:

```
$expansionExceptions = array('br', 'col', 'hr', 'img', 'input', 'link', 'meta', 'param', 'command', 'keygen');
$xml =& new DOMIT_Document();
$xml->expandEmptyElementTags(true, $expansionExceptions);
$xml->parseXML($htmlData);
$xml->toString( false );
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

All internal fields, import parameters and the testing page gives the same result. It seems to be a bug or bad implementation.

The most recent version is from 2005; I would switch to another parser if possible, or try to fix it using string operations.

Comment: Hi Duck,As I stated the problem is the other way around.
My XML is correctly parsed with & as &amp;

After DOMiT process it, all my &amp;s becomes &.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. It really behaves strange. I have researched it all day, tried different options, nothing. It also behaves the same on the testing document. It seems to be an implementation error. I've seen open source projects suffering from this issue have moved to other parsers. It may be your best bet to correct this using some string operations, or completely get rid of it if possible, considering the most recent version is from 2005 and parsers are better now.